# jest config - Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, next.js, config, ts-jest

I dont fully understand config files but having following issues when trying run jest unit test:

```
 Cannot find module '@/app/utils/regex' from 'src/_components/DriverSearchForm.tsx'
```

My jest.config

```
    import type { Config } from 'jest'
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
})

const config: Config = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/_components/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/_components/$1',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mjs)$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: 'tsconfig.test.json' }],
  },
}

export default createJestConfig(config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the alias of the module name, the value is the target module you want to map to. When you import from `@/app/utils/regex`, it will be mapped to the `<rootDir>/app/utils/regex` module.

`<rootDir>/jest.config.js`:

```json
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/app/$1',
}
```

`<rootDir>/tsconfig.json`:

```json
"paths": {
  "@/app/*": [
    "app/*"
  ]
}
```

`<rootDir>/app/utils/regex.ts`:

```
export const regex = /test/i
```

`index.ts`:

```
import { regex } from '@/app/utils/regex';

console.log(regex);
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import './';

describe('78224123', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(1 + 1).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.log
    /test/i

      at Object.log (stackoverflow/78224123/index.ts:3:9)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78224123/index.test.ts (7.62 s)
  78224123
    √ should pass (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.59 s
```